# regex preserve order in square brackets

Tags: python, regex

The context of the question is as follows. I wish to grab the file that wget is attempting to download, but need to ignore flags which may or may not appear.
eg. `wget -qO http://google.com/myfile.sh`. The expected output would be: `http://google.com/myfile.sh`. For this example the regex:

```
r'wget\s-\w+\s([^\s]*)'
```

seems to do the trick. However, will not work when there is no flag.

In order for the (possibly absent) flag to work I attempted: `r'wget\s[-\w+\s]?([^\s]*)'` which I was hoping would say that "you can expect 0 or 1 instance of a dash followed by some characters", however it seems to think that the order of the `-\w+\s` is optional, atleast that is my explanation of the following results:

```
import re
re.search(r'wget\s-\w+\s([^\s]*)','wget -qO http://google.com/myfile.sh').group(1)
>>> 'http://google.com/myfile.sh'
re.search(r'wget\s[-\w+\s]?([^\s]*)','wget -qO http://google.com/myfile.sh').group(1)
>>> 'q0'
re.search(r'wget\s[-\w+\s]*([^\s]*)','wget -qO http://google.com/myfile.sh').group(1)
>>> '://google.com/myfile.sh'
```

**Can someone explain the last two results, and show how to make sure that it matches 0 or more flags?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 wget\s*(?:-\w+)?\s*(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aDWM3X/1 for reference

The reason why your example was not working is because you are using brackets which means "any of the following characters or range" while also using + after \w (which does not mean 1 or more of \w, it means look for any \w, any + ....if you use a group then you can make the group optional with ? (zero or 1) or * if it can be zero or unlimited

Comment: Can you put a quick explanation as to what `(?:-\w+)` means?. Especially the first `(?:` which your link doesn't seem to explain. Finally why is this group described as non capturing in your link?